# putting images in IDLE

Tags: image, python-idle

I'm kinda new to programming, and I was wondering how to put JPG and/or PNG images into IDLE or py.exe (whichever it is running on). I know I can do it using Turtle Graphics or the TKINTER module, but what if I want to put it in IDLE?

Comment: IDLE is an IDE that one uses to write and run Python programs, including tkinter and turtle programs.  You question does not make much sense.  Just write and run your program and read images as normal.

Comment: What I want to do is put images where you print things. Right now I have to use ASCII art.

Comment: If you want to print images on paper, you must use special software intended to do that.  If you want to print images on a text console with Python's `print` function, you are out of luck.  Text consoles interpret the bytes they receive as coded characters.  If you otherwise want to put images on the screen, you must continue to use packages with methods intended to do so, such as tkinter.